# Parcel vue debugging: How can I map the output of parcel serve to my source code?

Tags: vue.js, parceljs

When I serve my Vue js app, I'm using `parcel serve index.html`
In the app, I placed a `debugger` keyword.

When running the app and open the dev tools in chrome I got something like this
[image: it stops at some random line]
It stops at some random line while I actually wanted to debug on the other part of my code 
[image]

How can I map the breakpoint to the intended part? does parcel able to do this? IIRC that called source map, right?
I read the docs seems only has the option to disable the source map

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems I have to delete the `dist` and `.cache` folder
now it works again